# ¿Cómo hacer esta consulta con Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Lo que deseo es sumar la fila points de la tabla activities_responses sólo cuando el usuario 1 y la actividad 1

```
SELECT SUM(points) as total FROM activities_responses where user_id = 1 and activities_id = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con el query builder de este modo

```
$data = DB::table("activities_responses")
 ->selectRaw("SUM(points) as total")
 ->where("user_id", 1)
 ->where("activities_id", 1)
 ->get();
```

- Usa el método `selectRaw()`; para pasar por dentro una instrucción SQL completa
- para usar el operador AND usa doble vez el método `where()`;

No olvides al inicio de tu contoller importar el namespace DB

```
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
```